# Instantiated UI Buttons getting unintended automatically moved along the Z-Axis

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

So i have this code which generates UI buttons. The buttons are initially placed at a specific x and y and z is 0. But when the script runs the x and y get assigned correctly while the z gets set to -572.0645. Due to this shift in the z-axis i can't see the buttons. Only if i reset the z-axis manually (what i obviously not want). I noticed that this only happens when i switch from Screen Space Overlay to Screen Space Camera.

```
        for (int i =0;i < div;i++){
            float x = 250 + 250 * Mathf.Cos(radianSteps*i);
            float y = (h/2) + 250 * Mathf.Sin(radianSteps*i);
            GameObject button = Instantiate(buttonTemplate,new Vector3(x,y,0),Quaternion.identity,transform);
            button.name = "Emotion "+i;
            TextMeshProUGUI textObject = button.transform.GetChild(0).GetComponent<TextMeshProUGUI>();
            textObject.text = emotionPairs[i];
            textObject.fontSize = 12;
            button.GetComponent<SelectEmotion>().emotionIndex = i;
            button.GetComponent<SelectEmotion>().maxIndex = div-1;
            button.GetComponent<SelectEmotion>().start = position;
            button.GetComponent<SelectEmotion>().dest = new Vector3((w-(w/4)),(h/2),0);
        }
```

[image]
Why are the buttons getting moved along the z-axis?

Comment: Well you said it yourself: This happens when switching between Screen Space Overlay to Screen Space Camera. With Screen Space Camera the canvas is placed a certain distance (in z-direction) away from the camera while in screen space overlay it's right on top. Why do you need to switch screen spaces though? Choose one, adjust the transforms. Done:)

Comment: @anjelomerte at the end i switched to World Space because i need to use a LineRenderer at the LineRenderer is not visible in the Screen Space Overlay. But anyways i solved the problem :)